# Can React or Next js use an api that returns an async stream of data (IAsyncEnumerable in .net)?

Tags: reactjs, .net, asynchronous, stream, ienumerable

With the introduction of `IAsyncEnumerable` interface in dot net applications, one can create an api that stream data asynchronously. Following [this](https://code-maze.com/csharp-async-enumerable-yield/) link.

If a react application consumes an `IAsyncEnumerable<int>` api which returns a sequence of numbers asynchronously, could this react application begin hydration before all the numbers are returned form that async api ?

For ex if the api returns 1 then waits 2 seconds and return 2 then waits 2 seconds and returns 3, can the react application update state each time a number is returned ? Or It should wait for all the numbers to be returned before executing its javascript logic ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@markotny97/streaming-iasyncenumerable-to-rxjs-front-end-8eb5323ca282
Maybe try this

Comment: @PeterT, that's correct, but for Angular. I answered with a React solution.

Answer (score 0):

As your link correctly states, that didn't became possible with the IAsyncEnumerable interface, which exists since .NET Core 3.0 (2019).

It only became possible after .NET 6 (2021).

It's possible to take advantage of that functionality in React using a special hook called 'useEffect' which became available in React 16.8:

[Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

While I understand in Stackoverflow it's better to answer the question ourselves instead of providing links, I wouldn't be capable of answering as well as Joe Morgan did here:

[How To Handle Async Data Loading, Lazy Loading, and Code Splitting with React](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-async-data-loading-lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-with-react)